# Margin/padding on IE7 problem - how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Why, with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gC4gP/14/) code, the `input type=text` get the `margin/padding` from the div parents? 
Input are `padded-top` of 50px (inherit from `.loc_title`) and `marged-left` of 30px (inherit from `loc_main`).

It really doesnt make sense :(

The funny things is that If I swap margin/padding on loc_main and loc_cerca the input get the right align! So I need to use padding with left-right and margin with top-bottom? I can't believe this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `overflow: visible` on the input field and the margins should disappear. It's a classic ie bug.